# geting password value from trocla within puppet erb template

Tags: puppet, erb

I have a template file (erb) in puppet which is actually the config file of a wordpress installation. The file looks like:

```
<?php
// DB config 
define('DB_NAME', 'wpdb');
define('DB_USER', 'myuser');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypass');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';
..
..
```

What i wish to achieve is to be able to get the DB_PASSWORD value from trocla. I know that this can be achieved on a manifest file with the following method:

```
$myvar=trocla('testuser:plain')
```

However i wish to use trocla on the template erb file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$myvar = '<%= scope.function_trocla(['testuser:plain']).gsub(%r{[\\']}, '\\\\\\0') %>';
```

See [Referencing Custom Functions In Templates](https://docs.puppet.com/guides/custom_functions.html#referencing-custom-functions-in-templates) in the manual.